# What does "Holding $f$ and $x$ fixed" mean, for instance, with $\frac{1}{2h}\left[f(x+h)-f(x-h)\right]$?

Tags: terminology

Reading on Richardson Extrapolation, in my textbook. The authors state that

> Holding $f$ and $x$ fixed we define a function of $h$ by the formula
> $$\phi(h) = \frac{1}{2h}\left[f(x+h)-f(x-h)\right]$$

I'm unsure what it means to be "Holding" a function and $x$ "Fixed".

Any help on defining these terms "Holding" and "Fixed" is much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: It just means you are considering the expression as a function of $h$ alone; $f$ is a  fixed function and $x$ is a fixed number.

Comment: To "hold fixed" means "to leave unchanged."